# Will matplotlib 1.2 be in 12.04 or 12.10?

Tags: python, repository

I found Windows installers for Matplotlib 1.2 for Python3 at this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

When will I be able to install matplotlib for python3 in Ubuntu from repositories? Will it be in 12.04 at all, or will I have to wait until 12.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The latest `python-matplotlib` **official release from the developers** is [1.1.1-rc2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/)
- So you will not see `python-matplotlib` 1.2 in 12.04 official repositories anytime soon.
- Consider that the current version of `python-matplotlib` in [Debian Sid](http://packages.debian.org/sid/python-matplotlib) is also *1.1.1-rc2*
- Ubuntu 12.10, currently in alpha, also contains [*1.1.1-rc2*](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/matplotlib)
- This is expected, since it's based on the packages in Debian Sid; 12.10 will be ["frozen" on August 23, 2012](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5MTE), and any package updates after that date will be rare (only critical stability fixes, etc.)
- So **bottom line**, unless `python-matplotlib` 1.2 makes it into Debian Sid before August 23, you may not see it upon 12.10 release either (although it may make it into updates)

Comment: So... Since python3 will be the only default installation of Python from 12.10, this means any application that is working with plots and is not compiled to binary will be unusable in 12.10? Unless of course you also install python2 (or find a way to manually add matplotlib with python3 support), but then there is no point of not supplying this from the start. This makes no sense to me...

Comment: @GaRyu: You may want to file a bug against the package in Launchpad...  Please remember to accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: OK, I've never had a chance yet to get involved in the development cycle so I don't understand the particulars very well. You mean I should go to the python-matplotlib package in Launchpad and put a bug on it that it won't work with the default Python version in 12.10?

Comment: Yes; if appropriate they will change the label to "feature-request"; don't worry about exact phrasing, the devs/commenters will make sure your point gets across. Not that there is any guarantee they will *do* something about it...

Answer (score 1):

so, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04,

and this seems to have worked for me.. while not directly from the repo, but does play nice without complexity of 'virtualenvironment' stuffs..

"Getting matplotlib running with python3"

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
wget https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/zipball/master
unzip master
cd matplotlib-matplotlib-bb3ea55 <=== the directory name will vary with version
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

thanks to 'Mike', as copied here from:  https://gist.github.com/mlongval/4950532